# Listen to keydown event of a text field using Prototype?

Tags: prototypejs, keydown

I want to listen to keydown events of a text field (input type=text) using Prototype. I managed to listen to the keydown event globally like this:

```
document.observe('keydown', myEventHandler);

function myEventHandler(evt) {
    alert(evt);
}
```

How can I listen to events only for my text fiekd with id "test" for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.observe('test','keydown',myEventHandler);

function myEventHandler(event) {
   alert(event);


}
```

Comment: or `$('test').observe('keydown',myEventHandler)`